# open files (pdf,image,) using angular

Tags: angular, api, file, blob

I have a local path in my server-side and I have to get this in angular and display it,
How should I do this?
I would love if anyone could tell me the way 
I understand I need to using blob in angular but what parameters do I get/return from the server?

here my Angular code

```
openPDF(){
this.ser.openDPFfile().subscribe((response)=>{
  let file = new Blob([response.byteString], { type: 'application/pdf' });            
  var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  window.open(fileURL);
}) }
```

and my c# code

```
  [RoutePrefix("api/files")]
    [Route("download")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetStreamFile()
    {
        string fileName = "LabResult.pdf";
        string path = @"C:/Users/" + fileName;
        byte[] a = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        string s = Convert.ToBase64String(a);
        return s;
    }
```

what i have to need to add or change?
please help me 
thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You can show your file in this way instead of converting it to Base64String and return it to angular, becuse it's time consuming.

```
window.open(
      'file path on the server',
      '_blank',
    );
```

Put your file somewhere in wwwroot folder and send this address to angular to open it like above.

Comment: Hey
Thanks for the feedback ...
But my path is a local path
Your way is only possible if the path is not local
Maybe I'm wrong?
I would be happy if you could explain it to me

Comment: I was wondering why you your files are on C drive?Why don't you put them in wwwroot folder?Because when you publish it on  a webserver ,you may have not access to drive C.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make pdf downloadable in your serverside code. When you make a request to your server the pdf file should be downloaded. Then you should use window.open function in your angular project to show that pdf. Old browsers can not show your pdf file.

this is your server side

```
// this is pseudo code
res.write(createReadStream('./mypdffile.pdf')
res.header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
res.header('Content-Length', 1000000) // 1megabyte
res.header('Content-Disposition', `attachment; myfile.pdf`)
```